# M2Eclipse: how define the Program Arguments such as the VM Arguments?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

I have a clear understanding about the difference between:

- `VM arguments`
- `Program arguments`

And how *define* them through the console/terminal and how *retrieve* them through the `Main` class. 
Until here I am ok

But through `Eclipse` or `STS`, the things are different.

For a simple Java application is possible define them as follows:

[image]

From above, is clear and straightforward where define these two sets or groups of values, again - until here I am ok too.

The situation is for a `Java` application working with `Maven` and therefore through `m2Eclipse` as follows:

[image]

From above, just playing or experimenting, I confirmed the following:

- The `VM arguments` can be defined in two ways: either directly the `Goals` text field
  or through the `Parameter Name/Value` area located in the bottom. Of course, better is the latter due presentation advantages and considering the scenario if exists many parameters/values to define

The problem is about `Program arguments`, only is possible define them through the `Goals` text field, therefore working with:

- `-Dexec.args="arg1 arg2 arg3"`

I could not find, through the other *tabs*, a similar support how exists for the `VM arguments`

- Am I missing something?
- Perhaps exists other plugin or patch that complements this case?
- or is totally mandatory work around `-Dexec.args="arg1 arg2 arg3"`?

The problem is when many `Program arguments` are need it.

By the moment I am using the `Goals` text field.

Comment: Could you please explain _why_ you want to run your application with the help of the maven exec plugin instead of just running it directly?

Comment: Because is a `Maven multi-module` project and this plugin through the `Resolve Workspace artifacts` checkbox lets refer the other dependencies quickly. And I want keep save any Maven Settings.

Comment: But when you just run a class from a module through Eclipse, the dependencies will also be resolved for you.

Comment: No, is mandatory have that checkbox marked.

Comment: I mean that if you just run it as "Java Application" as in your first image, then it also resolves dependencies.

Comment: I understand now, I did not work with the `Java Application` approach. I use m2 because I am able to save and reuse all my Maven configurations (explicit `Goals`) and reuse my modfied `settings.xml` file for Maven - it mostly to reuse my custom repository for all the dependencies need it. To be honest I use m2 because my app works with `Maven` so I skipped the `Java Application` approach from the beginning

Comment: I just asked because your approach appears to be unusual to me.

Comment: I understand, just being curious: can you share a Figure about the `Java Application` by your side but based for a _multi-module_ project? By my side the Main class for the sub module is not being detected by the IDE, so I can't run it